# Working of bitwise XOR on int operands of arrays

Tags: c, arrays, xor

I am just a beginner.So, the problem that I am facing is :-

How does the logic of bitwise XOR works in case of arrays?

For example in the code below:-

```
// Function to return the only odd occurring element
int findOdd(int arr[], int n) {
   int res = 0, i;
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
     res ^= arr[i];
   return res;
}

int main(void) {
   int arr[] = {12, 12, 14, 90, 14, 14, 14};
   int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
   printf ("The odd occurring element is %d ", findOdd(arr, n));
   return 0;
}
```

How, exactly, is the whole findOdd function working?
Can someone please explain the basic logic behind the use of xor in the above code example?

Comment: I don't understand the question. XOR cannot be used on arrays. Here it is used on `int` operands. Complexity? If you understand what that means, you will be able to find the complexity yourself.

Comment: As to what the function does, it picks out all the bits that are set an odd number of times in the values of the input array. The function is poorly named though. When passed `1` and `2`, for instance, it will return `3`.

Comment: 'The logic of bitwise XOR' has nothing to do with arrays. All you're doing is applying it to successive array *elements*, and there's nothing mysterious about that.

Answer (score 2):

You have used `bitwise XOR` , so it deals with binary bytes.  It is not directly applied on array but on binary representation of data stored in it .

And what function does is **to find number with odd occurrence in an array**.

And using property of `XOR` operations -

`XOR` of any number with itself gives us `0`,

`XOR` of any number with `0` gives us number itself.

We can understand the operations in each iteration-

```
1 iteration-  res=0(0000)^12(1100) -> res= 12(1100)  // just writing in decimal for clarity 
2 iteration-  res=12(1100)^12(1100) -> res=0(0000)   //operation is done on its binary representation
3 iteration-  res=0^14 ->  res=14
4 iteration-  res=14 (00001110) ^ 90 (01011010) ->  res=84 (01010100)
5 iteration-  res=84^14-> res=90
6 iteration-  res=90^14 -> res=84
7 iteration-  res=84^14-> res=90
```

Therefore , `res` return `90` as result.

> When do we use the bitwise XOR in arrays?

It perform operations on bits , not on a whole array.And is used in similar way as we use it on two numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The findOdd function uses the ^ or bitwise xor operator.

You already know about arithmetic operators like +, or -, etc.

The xor operator has some [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Properties) in common with addition and multiplication. It is:

1. Commutative (ie. A xor B is the same as B xor A)
2. Associative (ie. A xor (B xor C) is the same as (A xor B) xor C).

The bitwise xor simply does the xor operation on each bit of the operands in parallel. Given these two properties, we can xor the array elements in any order without altering the result.

Now, consider the bitwise xor of 2 numbers. It is always 0:

```
A^A == 0
```

For every evenly occurring number, we can pair them up, and the bitwise xor of these pairs are 0.

Therefore, the bitwise xor of the array, is the bitwise xor of the oddly occurring elements of the array.

If there is only one element which occurs an odd number of times, findOdd will return this number.

However, be warned, that if there are more than one set of oddly occurring numbers, the function will not do what you might expect.

Eg. taking the xor of `{5, 2, 2, 7}`, the 2's cancel out, but we are left with, which is `5^7 = 0b101 ^ 0b111 = 0b010 = 2`.

Comment: I like this answer. I was looking at  ameyCU's answer and thinking, well what happens if we stop at line "6 iteration-  res=90^14 -> res=84", this answer answers that.

Answer (score 1):

Working of `xor` on arrays is not different from normal `xor` or `bitwise xor`. To understand the logic better, following are the properties of `xor`.

- `xor` of same bits returns 0
- `xor` of different bits returns 1

Now, The array contains only one element that occurs odd number of times. So, When `xor` is applied on two same numbers, result is `0` and `xor` of `0` and any number gives the number itself.

Hence, when we `xor` all the elements in the array, even occurrences cancel out by returning `0` and final result remains as the only odd occurring element.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks @Karthik, but If I am not wrong,res variable  is first set to zero and then it's being XORed with the first number of the array. But the number obtained would be cancelled or not depending on whether the first element of array would be zero or not, wouldn't that lead to some kind of ambiguity in the result?

Comment: @AkankshaSingh yes.. which will make result equal to the 1st number in the array and then the `for loop` continues.. :)

Comment: *The array contains only one element that occurs odd number of times.* That's completely irrelevant. I don't think you understand what the function does. Admittedly its name misleads.

Comment: @AkankshaSingh yes.. the result could be anything (any number that is not even in the array) before the end of the loop.. but according to the condition that the array has only one odd occurrence of a number it will return that number..

Comment: @David, I hope this doesn't sound stupid.But When we use XOR on the series of numbers, how are the bits being compared?
eg 0 1 3 4 0 3 4    , how does the XOR result looks like ?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes.. I understood the question.. and i agree that the name is misleading :)

Comment: @karthik No. That's not even remotely close to the truth. Consider some examples. Suppose the input is 1, 2 and 3. Then what is the output? All values appear exactly once. Function can't return all of them. In fact it returns 0. Because each bit appears twice. In binary input is 01, 10 and 11.

Comment: @Akanksha You need to go back to basics. Write the numbers in the question in binary. Then xor then all together. Do that with some different inputs. Then you'll understand.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Actually, I tried to explain the same thing.. and **here** the input you took is not a valid one.. because the function is to be applied on an array which has only `one` element occurring odd number of times :)

Comment: No such requirement is stated anywhere that I can see

Comment: @DavidHeffernan check the comment in the 1st line of the code.. `// Function to return the only odd occurring element`

Comment: I'd regard that as a non sequitur. In order to call the function safely, you'd already know the answer!!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Now that entirely depends on how we perceive things.. I never consider comments as irrelevant because code could be wrong and naming of functions and variables could be misleading.. but never the comments! :)

Comment: As I said, that interpretation leaves the function useless because you can only call it when you know the answer. As for comments always being accurate, that's rather naive.